# How to programmatically take a quiz with multiple questions

Tags: hooks, quiz

I have one quiz with multiple questions.I got a solution for taking quiz with multiple questions.

```
$account = user_load($quiz_taker_uid);
// Load quiz and question nodes
$quiz = node_load($quiz_nid);
$question = node_load($question_nid);
// Create a new result id
db_query("INSERT INTO {quiz_node_results} (nid, vid, uid, time_start) VALUES (%d, %d, %d, %d)", $quiz->nid, $quiz->vid, $account->uid, time());
$rid = db_last_insert_id('quiz_node_results', 'result_id');
// Submit the answer
$result = quiz_question_evaluate_question($question, $rid, $long_answer_text);
quiz_store_question_result($quiz, $result, array('set_msg' => FALSE));
// Finish the scoring and properly invoke hooks
$score = quiz_end_scoring($quiz, $rid);
quiz_end_actions($quiz, $rid, $score);
```

change one line in above code // passing the number of question .

```
quiz_store_question_result($quiz, $result, array('question_data'=>array('number' =>1)));
```

But I  got another problem. score could not be updated.

Comment: any luck if your tried to update the score programatically?